# грокаем алгоритмы стр.156 алгоритм дейкстры

Tags: python, алгоритм

Сейчас читаю книгу "Грокаем алгоритмы". Реализовал поиск в ширину на пайтоне

```
graph = {}
graph["s"] = {"a","b"}
graph["a"] = {"e"}
graph["b"] = {"a","e"}
graph["e"] = {}

def searchBFS(key, find):
    search_queue = deque()
    search_queue += graph[key]
    searched =[]
    while search_queue:
        obj = search_queue.popleft()
        print("obj:", obj)
        if not obj in searched:
            if obj == find:
                print("Bingo found object")
                return True
            else:
                search_queue += graph[obj]
                searched.append(obj)
    return False
```

граф представляет собой представленную матрицу смежности по алгоритму Дейкстры из 4 вершин (но не реализация Дейкстры) , в книге пишется, что мол использование "поиска в ширину" даст самый короткий путь от начала до конца, но этого нет, при ряде тестовых запусков количество вершин всегда полное - то есть, все вершины проходятся до конечной искомой точки, и где там "самый короткий путь"?   Или ошибка, или я чего-то недогоняю?

Answer (score 0):

То, что в данном случае выводятся обрабатываемые узлы, не значит, что они участвуют в найденном пути. Если добавить ещё узел

```
graph["b"] = {"f","a","e"}
graph["e"] = {}
graph["f"] = {"e"}
```

то он не будет обработан и выведен.

При необходимости вывода кратчайшего пути его нужно регистрировать - например, при добавлении узла в очередь ещё записывать, откуда в него пришли, тогда потом можно размотать цепочку обратно.